# Keyerror while trying to pull Zipcode from Google Reverse Geocoding

Tags: python, keyerror

Am new to Python and am trying to parse out just the zip code from a list (using Googlemaps package) and am running into a KeyError.

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client('my_api_key')
reverse_geocode_result = gmaps.reverse_geocode((lat,lng))
address = reverse_geocode_result
x=address[0][0]
print(len(x))
```

Error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Gmaps2.py", line 10, in 
    x=address[0][0]
KeyError: 0

Comment: What is the value of `address` before the `x=address[0][0]` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

address[0] should be a dictionary object - you can access its contents with keys, rather than using a numerical index (which is something you would do for a list).

```
>>> address[0].keys()
[u'geometry', u'address_components', u'place_id', u'formatted_address', u'types']

>>> address[0]['address_components'][8]['long_name']
u'90005'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved my issue.Is there a way to find out which ones are lists and which ones are dictionary. It seems like in this case address[0]['address_components'][6].keys() worked while address[0]['address_components'].keys() did not.

Comment: @avogadro - `type(object_name)` will tell you the type of an object. address[0]['address_components'][6] references the sixth object of a list, not the list itself; that object is presumably a dict, so you can get its keys. You'll get the hang of it after you've had a bit more experience with python, specifically, with lists and dictionaries.